# Node Express Poller Blocked by computational intensive route

Tags: node.js, express

I am polling my node/express app while a computational intensive function is running. Now this function blocks node / express somehow from replying instantly to the http-get requests; instead these poller requests are getting queued up and return all after the computation is finished.

Is there a module or technique to allow node to "breath" and reply to http requests?

**Inside my main route**

```
module.exports.parse = (req, res) ->

 # Synchronously Cascading Waterfalls

  async.waterfall [
    (next) ->
      MyOtherOtherModel.findById req.params.id, (err, data) ->
        if err
          next err
        if !data._id
          dataError = new Error "Fatal error: Data Result is empty!"
          next dataError
        next null, data

    (data, next) ->
      fs.readdir 'uploads', (err, files) ->
        if err
          next err
        next null, data, files

    (data, files, next) ->

      async.each files, ((file, callback) ->
        # Do intensive stuff here, parsing, I/O, mapping, etc

        async.waterfall [
          (innerNext) ->
            MyOtherModel.findByIdAndUpdate data._id,
              { # data
                $push:
                  'uploadedFiles':
                    fileName: file
                    length: data.length
              },
              { # options
                safe: true
                upsert: true
                new: true
              }, (err, dataObjects) ->
                if err
                  innerNext err
                innerNext null, dataObjects
          (dataObjects, innerNext) ->
            async.each items, ((item, innerCallback) ->
              MyModel.create myData, (err, result) ->
                if err
                  innerCallback err
                innerCallback null
            ), (err) ->
              if err
                innerNext err
              innerNext null
        ], (err) ->
          if err
            callback err
          callback null
      ), (err) ->
        if err
          next err
        # Leave node room to breath, but it isnt working
        setTimeout (->
          next null
        ), 1000
    ], (err) ->
      if err
        throw Error err # All Errors bubble up to this point

  # We return immediately, so that express is free to handle poller requests

  res.status(202).send
    status: 'OK'
    error: 'Started Computation.'
  return
```

**My Poller**

```
module.exports.poll = (req, res) ->

  # Ask DB and calculate finishedPercentage

  res.status(206).send
    status     : 'Partial Content'
    type       : 'info'
    error      : percentageFinished + ' % geparsed.'
    progress     : percentageFinished
```

*Console Output*

```
Parsing..
nextFile..
nextFile..
nextFile..
nextFile..
Progress: 100.0 %
Progress: 100.0 %
...
```

So you can see the poller is somehow queued until Node thinks its about time to answer the http requests. I want this progress to continuously be updated.

Comment: Can you explain "computational intensive route?" What exactly is it doing?

Comment: Updated my Question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to delegate the CPU intensive task(s) to a [child process](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html) that reports progress updates occasionally either by node's [built-in message passing mechanism](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_callback) or simply by writing to stdout and having the parent process relay that information back to the client.

Comment: Thats awesome. Let me try it tomorrow and then decide on giving you the answer. Upvoted already.

Comment: Is it possible to just "duplicate" node for the runtime of the child process? I need all my mongoose models, config, etc pp for above async task to be accessible. Do you have an example?

Comment: There is [`child_process.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), but as the documentation notes, it's not a process clone like *nix `fork()`. However I think it may still work for your purposes.